# How do you let a user input a decimal number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimal

I am trying to make a program related to money and the user needs to input a decimal. But it always gives me an error. Here is the code:

```
price = input("What is the price of your vegetable?")
pounds = input("How many pounds did you buy?")

price = int(price)
pounds = int(pounds)

if pounds < 5:
    price = price * 1
    print("Your price is " + str(price))
elif pounds < 10:
    price = price * 0.90
    print("Your price is " + str(price))
elif pounds < 20:
    price = price * 0.80
    print("Your price is " + str(price))
elif pounds > 30:
    price = price * 0.75
    print("Your price is " + str(price))
```

And here is the error:

```
What is the price of your vegetable?6.72
How many pounds did you buy?4
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Jerry Cui/Documents/pricediscount.py", line 4, in <module>
    price = int(price)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '6.72'
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: `int` is for integers.

Answer (score 2):

**Use [`float()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) instead of [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int):**

```
price = float(price)
pounds = float(pounds)
```

---

- [**`int()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) converts to an integer
- [**`float()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) converts to a decimal

Answer (score 1):

Use `float()` as you want to allow entry of floats!

**However,** I suggest you [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3730040/7434365), which hopefully will convince you to right something along the lines of:

```
price = input("What is the price of your vegetable? (pounds.pence, e.g: 3.42)")
price = int(price.replace(".", ""))
```

Now the price is stored as an integer, which is *much* more accurate than a float; especially when storing money (hence we use `int()` here again).

Comment: This is bad. Now entering `12.34` will lead to the same result als entering `123.4`.

Answer (score 0):

If your dealing with financial data it is best to employ the decimal module.  The according to the docs see [decimal — Decimal fixed point and floating point arithmetic](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) the module provides support for fast correctly-rounded decimal floating point arithmetic. It offers several advantages over the float datatype.  To use in your particular situation:

```
price = input("What is the price of your vegetable? (pounds.pence, e.g: 3.42)")
price = Decimal(price).quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN))
```

As examples:
`print(Decimal('12.345').quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)))` -> 12.34  , and

`print(Decimal(''123.0056'').quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)))` -> 123.00